# need recomandation to create forms in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I want to have 4 different forms in Drupal 8 with each form will have an approximate 250 - 300 fields.

There will be a huge data (count)

Now what module / approach I choose in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a custom form:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

Or you can use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. If you going to use webform module with that many fields I recommend createing all the fields with yml builder (via UI) because it will be faster.

Decision what is better in your example is based on your coding skills (webforms are easier), how many reusable components you need (reusable componnents could be managed easier programatically - custom form) and if you see an option that you can make all fields programatically with an ease.